# Python3 Crypto.Hash - SHA digest always starts with binary 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, pycrypto

I am working on a project where I am trying to create a very simple blockchain-based cryptocurrency. This is an oversimplified version of the way I try to hash a block object (obviously the fields of the `Block` class are much more complicated, but this is the main idea):

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from random import random

class Block(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def to_dict(self):
        d = OrderedDict({
            'x' : self.x,
            'y' : self.y,
            'z' : self.z
        })
        return d

    def json(self):
        return json.dumps(self.to_dict())

    def hash(self):
        return SHA.new(self.json().encode('utf8')).hexdigest()

# driver code to test hashing
while True:
    x, y, z = [random() for _ in range(3)]
    b = Block(x, y, z)
    if not bin(int(b.hash(), 16)).startswith('0b1'):
        break
```

The above driver program loops forever. The problem is that (regardless of the number and/or value of the fields) the hash ALWAYS starts with `0b1`, which messes with the whole idea of mining difficulty and proof-of-work. More importantly, though, this is not the expected behavior of a hashing function. What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't zero pad the front of binary numbers by default, so the first digit of *any* binary number will be one.

```
>>> bin(1)
'0b1'
>>> bin(2)
'0b10'
>>> bin(3)
'0b11'
>>> bin(8)
'0b1000'
```

If you want fixed with binary strings, use string formatting

```
>>> "{:04b}".format(1)
'0001'
>>> "{:04b}".format(2)
'0010'
>>> "{:04b}".format(8)
'1000'
>>> "{:04b}".format(15)
'1111'
```

Otherwise, just use a binary and (`&`) to check if the specific bit is set.

```
>>> bool(1 & 0b1000)
False
>>> bool(3 & 0b1000)
False
>>> bool(8 & 0b1000)
True
>>> bool(15 & 0b1000)
True
```

Comment: "...the first digit of any binary number will be one." Except for zero, naturally.

Comment: Thank you very much! After reading your answer, I also found that `format(int(h, 16), '0256b')` will do the trick, if `h` is a hex representation of the hash (as a string).